# WordPress - Automatic logout when using different browser / IP

Tags: wordpress, authentication, cookies

I'm afraid I cannot get through this problem on my own. It is weird that this issue seems to be unique for my installation.

On my WordPress-based website users are having trouble with the login, especially when using their mobile phones to authenticate: they are being logged out (even when checking "Remember me") and will have to re-enter their credentials (after which they're logged out again). From what I figured, it is most likely the fact that their respective mobile Internet Service Providers dynamically assign new IP addresses to their devices all the time, causing the authentication to fail.

When I'm using my desktop to login, everything will work just fine. However, say, I have successfully logged in to the site with Google Chrome, and I open an instance of Mozilla Firefox (or any other browser) to log in simultaneously, Chrome's user "session" will be shut down immediately (I know that because an asynchronous script is requesting whether or not the user is logged in and it prompts me to log in once I sign in using the other browser). Therefore I believe that the whole WordPress authentication has got something to do with the user agent, too.

*Albeit I highly appreciate the extra amount of security provided by automatically voiding a running session when accessing the site from a different IP or browser, my users do not. Even for myself it is remarkably cumbersome, using three different machines plus tablet and phone to access the site from any possible place (eventually I stopped bothering to log in and just waited to get home).*

Since WordPress authentication uses cookies, I looked into how these are generated. The `wp_generate_auth_cookie()` method uses the user name, parts of their hashed password, the expiration time and a salt (a constant salt defined in `wp-config.php`), but neither does it use the IP address nor the user agent. 
I literally searched the whole WordPress folder for "user agent" or "IP address" occurrences but there is no login-related script containing the terms (merely a handful of plugins that don't affect the user session at all).

That puzzles me. How does WordPress even realize that I am logged in with a different browser / computer if it doesn't store that data with the authentication cookie? And where does the check happen that logs me and my users out?

Do you have any further ideas on how to troubleshoot the issue?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Harti

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are stored by browsers and different browsers on the same machine don't share that storage. Thus when you login with Chrome, WP sends a login cookie to Chrome, starting a new session. When you then access the site with Firefox, FF doesn't have a login cookie so WP prompts you to login and then sends a login cookie to FF, also starting a new session. The next time you access the site with Chrome, it gets Chrome's login cookie, which doesn't match the last one sent out that's associated with your username, so everything starts all over again.

This doesn't directly explain the problem with mobile devices; it sounds like for some reason they aren't storing the cookies properly.

Comment: I wonder, though, why WordPress knows that it has sent a new cookie in another browser - maybe due to a new expiration time. However, when authenticating the cookie I cannot find any comparison with a database or something - where might that data be stored?